# "meteor mongo" crashes with "Error: EINVAL, invalid argument"

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/3-way-data-binding) and am stuck at "inserting parties from the console"... I can't run "meteor mongo"

Here is my output:

```
$ meteor.bat mongo

C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_3 2\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^ Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
    at new Socket (net.js:157:18)
    at process.stdin (node.js:687:19)
    at Command.main.registerCommand.name [as func] (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.m            eteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\commands.js:1036:12)
    at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.window s.x86_32\tools\main.js:1363:23
```

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7 SP1, and have tried restarting to no use.  In case this is relevant using control-C doesn't kill the meteor server, so I have been killing all the node.exe processes manually through the task manager instead.

This is my first time using meteor, and can't find this replicated anywhere.

** EDIT **
This works using the DOS prompt, but not the cygwin terminal

Thank you, and let me know if you need more info about anything!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this time meteor on Windows can ONLY be used via the "cmd" prompt.  Not even PowerShell will work.  Nor does git-bash (in case you were wondering -- I tried that too).

Just do all your meteor commands from a "cmd" shell and you should avoid lots of little issues I think.

One nice thing -- when you want to build/deploy your app -- the nice little tool "demeteorizer" DOES work fine on cygwin/git-bash. :)

Comment: Hm, running meteor and deploying meteor works fine in git bash for me, but mongo crashes with the above exception for me too.